# How to invoke custom (java) program on Websphere Liberty Profile startup

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

How can i start a specific java program when a server instance has been started from within Websphere Liberty Profile?

eg. '> server start test' should start the server + start my specific java program (with a parameter if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no builtin mechanism for this, so your best option would be to write a [Liberty profile product extension](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/cwlp_prod_ext.html) that launches the extra program when the server starts.  Specifically, write a feature that contains an OSGi bundle that contains a BundleActivator with a start method that launches the program.